# Detecting taps on any surface by iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I am developing an app in which I need to put my iPhone on any surface and detect the taps on that surface. Please provide me any link or idea regarding that.
Thanks.

Comment: You could try to detect sound of taps or try to use acccelerometer to detect vibrations from taps. Or both.

Comment: can you provide any link or source code for the same..

Comment: Unfortunately, no, it's just an idea. If I could I would make it an answer, not a comment :)

Comment: Thanks for ur reply but the problem with accelerometer is that it detects even the simple move of the phone, so that is not at all useful to me. I just want detection only when a particular surface is tapped. eg my phone is on a table,then it should detect table taps.

Comment: Well, it would take time and research, but I think it should be possible to differ taps from phone movement. Taps are short and not intensive. You could set an upper limit for accelerotemer signal intensity (I've never worked with accelerometer, I'm just guessing) and duration. May be even use some sort of neural network for this purpose.

Comment: Also you could use a gyro to make sure that the phone is lying still.

Answer (score 2):

See sample code out there for using the accelerometer to detect movement. 
Then test varying amounts of detected movement and determine what you think is  "tap".

Answer (score 1):

As a suggestion - you could use the accelerometer in the phone to detect vibrations. I'm not sure if it will be accurate enough for you, and you will need to do some processing of the results to filter for the correct type of vibration.

This isn't simple, so if you were hoping for some code or library to do this I don't think you'll find what you need.

If you do manage to do it, you could open source your implementation and help the next person who comes along.